# How to read climate research data (CRU) correctly using ncdf4 package in R?

Tags: r, netcdf

CRU netCDF data has monthly average values. My file has data for the period of 1901-1910. When I read the variable (tmp), it shows only 12 levels out of 120 months in 10 years.

```
library(ncdf4)
nc<- nc_open(file.choose())
lat<- ncvar_get(nc, "latitude")
lon<- ncvar_get(nc, "longitude")
tm<- ncvar_get(nc, "tmp")

dim(tm)
[1] 720 360  12
```

link of data file is here:-
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9ACBRSUXCjnWWxZclR3alNIdEE

Comment: I think my answer solved your problem - please can you tick the green arrow to mark as accepted answer so this question can be closed?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the header of the file

```
ncdump -h cru_tmp_clim_1901-1910.nc
```

you will see that the file only has 12 timeslices.

```
netcdf cru_tmp_clim_1901-1910 {
dimensions:
time = 12 ;
latitude = 360 ;
longitude = 720 ;
bounds = 2 ;
```

If you use cdo:

```
cdo showdate cru_tmp_clim_1901-1910.nc 
1905-01-16  1905-02-15  1905-03-16  1905-04-16  1905-05-16  1905-06-16  1905-07-16  1905-08-16  1905-09-16  1905-10-16  1905-11-16  1905-12-16
```

you see that the data is only for 1905.

I think someone has passed you a data file that has been cut down.  I would advise re-downloading the original CRU data from source.  Remember, if you have doubts, always good to use ncdump to example the file header and metadata to see what is in there.